# Android whats the name of inapp web broswer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have seen some apps (can't remember them) using a different kind of web browser, it's not a `WebView` neither full browser like chrome, I tried searching online but I didn't have the right keywords to find it, what its name and how do I use inside my app

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604150/embedded-chromium-or-webkit-in-android-app

Comment: @KooroshGhorbani I don't think its what I'm looking for

Comment: how do you know its not a web view

Comment: Probably a [Chrome Custom Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), see [WebView vs Chrome Custom Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42689996/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you, its what was I looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [Chrome Custom Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client for examples.

Of course this will require Chrome to be installed on device.

Related: [WebView vs Chrome Custom Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42689996/295004)